# Use-case for requestError http interceptor

Tags: angularjs

According to [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) an interceptor has following methods:

```
request: function(config) {
  //we could manipulate query here
  return config || $q.when(config);
},
requestError: function(rejection) {
  // what is the use case of this?
  return $q.reject(rejection);
},
response: function(response) {
  // response.status === 200
  return response || $q.when(response);
},
responseError: function(rejection) {
  // when response failed ...
  return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

How is `requestError` triggered and what use-cases can you think of?

Comment: How about connection error message displaying after failed attempt to send request?

Comment: @AndreyShustariov hm no when $http cannot connect to resource because the resource is offline, responseError is triggered

Comment: Ok. Then bad formatted request. For example, forgot to set url property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One interesting use case is to tear down / undo things that have been set up before a request, and would have been teared down after a response. Examples:

- loading indicator
- overlay
- disabled form fields

Now when the request can't be sent or is rejected by another interceptor, `requestError` gives you the chance to act appropriately and remove that loading indicator or enable the form fields.